# Extract text from pdf java android

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract the raw text from a pdf file with android studio java (api 26 min and api33 is the emulator) and apache pdfbox

This is my code. There seems to be a problem with converting a uri to an ordinary file, because I get a FileNotFoundException error in this line "FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdf);". I'm not 100% sure if uri.getPath() really gives me the path I need for a file.

Thanks for any help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        try {
                            readTextFromPDF(uri);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void chooseFile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        resultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    private void readTextFromPDF(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        File pdf = new File(uri.getPath());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdf);

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fis);
        PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfTextStripper.getText(document);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.test);
        textView.setText(text);

        document.close();
        fis.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: to solve the first point is to understand what uri.getPath() returns. try to run in debug or putting a log and read what the instruction return.
i tell this because File pdf = new File(uri.getPath()); should be correct.

Comment: So the log gives me "/document/document:1000000018" which kinda looks wrong to me as a file path idk. I also figured out know what uri even is (I remembered websites xD) but still the problem remains. You are right there is no problem with the new File(uri.getPath()); but I do not really get the error at the fis. Do I have to save the File somewhere or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Uri.getPath() does not give you a path to a file.

You got a nice uri and that uri gives you access to the file.

Uri.toString() shows you the content scheme.

Just open an InputStream for the obtained uri.

The rest is the same as with FileInputStream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: Just to empasize here-  a picker doesn't have to return a file.  It returns a URI, because the content may not be a file-  it could be a result returned by an app with a content provider.  Except in very specific circumstances you can't assume file, so use the content resolver APIs.

Comment: Thank you it kind of worked but now I got an error at the PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fis); line.

Comment: It is a ClassNotFoundException because java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Point;. I am new to pdfbox, could there be the problem?

Comment: So yeah, the version of pdfbox didnt work with gradle, but I fixed it now and it works thanks!